# JQuery Problem: Why doesn't $(document).scroll() work in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

This simple code works in firefox but not IE (8 and below). Is there a way to make it work?

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    alert('foo');
});
```

I'm just trying to detect when the user is scrolling on a page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try using $(window).scroll()